# Why I got "sequelize.literal is not a function" in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I try to clone my project to new PC then I got an error call "sequelize.literal is not a function".

This is my product controller. I try to get my product with avg_rating by using literal function.

```
const Product = require("../models").product;

module.exports = {
getProduct: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let query = {}
    query.where = {
        isPublished: 1
    };
    query.attributes = {
      include: [
        sequelize.literal(
          `(SELECT CAST(AVG(rating) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) FROM product_reviews WHERE productId = \`Product\`.\`id\`)`
        ),
        "avg_rating",
      ]
    }

    const product = await Product.findAll(query)

    res.send({
      status: 200,
      data: product,
    });

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
},
}
```

For the result

> Status 500 & error: "sequelize.literal is not a function"

My package.json here.

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "NuChaiyakorn",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.1.7-alpha.3",
    "express-promise-router": "^3.0.3",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "ffmpeg": "0.0.4",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "ramda": "^0.27.0",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.6",
    "slugify": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code for us buddy?

Comment: perhaps the `package.json` as well?

Comment: Updated. Please see in above.

Comment: I believe use of literal in a query has been deprecated and replaced with raw query functions:

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem by adding this line to the top of controller.

```
const { sequelize } = require('../models/index')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `attributes` should be as follows -

```
query.attributes = [
  [sequelize.literal(`(SELECT CAST(AVG(rating) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) FROM product_reviews WHERE productId = \`Product\`.\`id\`)`), 'avg_rating']
];
```

You also need to specify what extra attributes along with `avg_rating` which are required in the response.

For example -

```
query.attributes = [
  'id',
  ['name','userName'],
  [sequelize.literal(`(SELECT CAST(AVG(rating) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) FROM product_reviews WHERE productId = \`Product\`.\`id\`)`), 'avg_rating']
];
```

I tried to use `attributes` with `include` as you have used but I didn't get expected response.

Comment: I got the same result "sequelize.literal is not a function"

Comment: I use this query in my old laptop I can get the response from it. This error only occur when I clone this projects to my new laptop sir.